# Holt-Winters forecasting method

Tags: time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

Holt-Winters forecasting equations for quarterly observations are

$\alpha_t = \alpha.\frac{y_t}{s_{t-4}} + (1-\alpha) . (\alpha_{t-1} + g_{t-1} )$

$g_t=\gamma.(\alpha_{t}-\alpha_{t-1})+(1-\gamma).g_{t-1}$

$s_t = \delta.\frac{y_t}{\alpha_{t}} + (1-\delta) . s_{t-4}$

The prediction formula for k period ahead at period T is

$\hat{y_{T+k}}=(\alpha_T+k.g{T}).s_{T-4+k}$

Suppose $\alpha=\gamma=\delta=0.2$, $\alpha_4=2$, $g_4=2$, and

$S_1=0.8, s_2=1, s_3=1, s_4=1.2$

Forecast $y_5$ to $y_8$ at $T=4$. Also assuming $y_5= 10$, find $a_5$, $g_5$ and $s_5$.

Answer:

Calculating $\alpha_5$:

$\alpha_5 = \alpha y_5s_1 + (1-\alpha)(\alpha_4+g_4)
= 0.2100.8 + 0.8(2+2)
= 2.24$

Calculating $g_5$:

$g_5 = \gamma*(\alpha_5-\alpha_4) + (1-\gamma)g_4
= 0.2(2.24-2) + 0.8*2
= 2.04$

Calculating $s_5$:

$s_5 = \delta y_5\alpha_5 + (1-\delta)s_1
= 0.2102.24 + 0.80.8
= 1.216$

Therefore, $\alpha_5=2.24, g_5=2.04$, and $s_5=1.216$.

Now we can use the prediction formula to forecast $y_5$ to $y_8$:

$\hat {y_5} = (\alpha_5g_5)s_1 = 4.5936$

$\hat{y_6} = (\alpha_6g_6)s_2 = (0.24.5936+0.82.04)(1.2) = 5.37312$

$\hat{y_7} = (\alpha_7g_7)s_3 = (0.25.37312+0.82.04)(1) = 2.870752$

$\hat{y_8} = (\alpha_8g_8)s_4 = (0.22.870752+0.82.04)*(1.2) = 3.3515392$

I don't know how $T=4$ affects the results. Also, $K$?

Comment: You need to iteratively update your variables. A spreadsheet like MS Excel may be useful.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I wrote my answer. Could you please open it? Thanks

Comment: I just cast the third vote to reopen. Please go ahead and post your answer!